# JavaScript: AWS Amplify : How to get the User Id(Sub ID) after user signs Up. After SignsUP not Sign In

Tags: javascript, reactjs, aws-amplify

I am using the Auth Module Provided by Aws Amplify.I am contemplating how can I retrieve the
userID once the user signs up.

I can get the ID once the user Signs In, however, I want to get the  userID during SignUp Process so I can update some of my model before logging in.

I didn't see userId in my signUp response. I am wondering if there is any workaround for that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Id is contained in the `userSub` part of the response, so `result.userSub`.

```
Auth.signUp({
    username: username,
    password: password,
    attributes: attributes
}).then((result) => {
    console.log(result.userSub)
})
```

In response to comment:

The result from signUp is:

```
{
    user: CognitoUser;
    userConfirmed: boolean;
    userSub: string;
}
```

Source: https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/emailpassword/q/platform/js/#sign-up

Comment: There is no such property called userSub in result

Comment: You might want to check again or review your code - I've updated the expected response and given source URL. I've also tested it in my own code and can confirm the User ID is returned via userSub as expected.

Comment: Thanks, I was only destructuring {user} from Auth.SignUP. I appreciate your response.